# Can i upload a new app bundle with same version code?

Tags: android, android-app-bundle, app-bundle

Can i upload a new app bundle with same version code?

I asked this question because i can upload a new app bundle with same version code in internal app sharing? Is same thing possible for Internal,Alpha, Beta and Release production?

Answer (score 3):

[No](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning)

> You cannot upload an APK to the Play Store with a versionCode you have already used for a previous version.

Comment: of course but i don't mean apk, it is app bundle aab file.

Comment: it holds true for aab files as well. When you upload it to the Play Store Google will take your app bundle and generate an APK which needs to adhere to the version code policy.